# Within a loop, match items with values in a dataframe column, then store a separate column value as a variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have an existing loop that I am using to go through a large amount of file paths, which ultimately sends the files through a cloud processing pipeline. I need to update the loop to match the file names with a dataframe column (`fileName`), then get the associated data values from a second column (`date`) and store that as a variable in my loop.

```
# dataframe that I need to extract 'date' from
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['dat1', 'dat2', 'dat3'],
        'date':[2019, 2021, 2015],
        'fileName': ['dat1.file', 'dat2.file', 'dat3.file']})


# list of file paths that I need the fileName from to match with my dataframe
gs_files = ['path/dat1.file', 'path/dat2.file']
bucket = 'path/'


for f in gs_files:
    # get file path
    print('Path: ', f)

    # get file name (need to keep this for later processing steps)
    fbname = f.replace(bucket, '')
    print('Image name: ', fbname)

    # match fbname with df['fileName']. Store associated 'date' as a separate variable (not as a column in df)
    if fbname in df['fileName']:
        year = df['date']
        print('Collection date: ',year)

    # Extra processing steps will be executed below.
```

```
# Resulting output from the above code:
Path:  path/dat1.file
Image name:  dat1.file
Path:  path/dat2.file
Image name:  dat2.file

# Desired output:
Path:  path/dat1.file
Image name:  dat1.file
Collection date: 2019

Path:  path/dat2.file
Image name:  dat2.file
Collection date: 2021
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code:

```
if fbname in df['fileName']:
    year = df['date']
    print('Collection date: ',year)
```

to this:

```py
if df['fileName'].isin([fbname]).any():
    year = df['date'][df['fileName'] == fbname].iloc[0]
    print('Collection date: ',year)
```

`fbname in df['fileName']` doesn't work. Instead, `df['fileName'].isin([fbname])` will return a new column containing `True` for each item in the original column that's in the list you specify (`[fbname]`), `False` otherwise. Then, `.any()` returns `True` if there is at least one `True` in the column it's called on.

Also, `df['date'][df['fileName'] == fbname]` selects the items from `date` where `fileName` is `fbname`. `.iloc[0]` gets the actual value out.

Comment: ok thanks, that helped me properly get all of the dates with matching file names, but I am still not indexing the date properly in `year = df['date']` The output from your suggested code gives `Path:  path/dat1.file
Image name:  dat1.file
Collection date:  0    2019
1    2021
2    2015` I still need to extract the specific date for a given file

Comment: @nkwilder check my answer now. I wasn't paying full attention when I wrote it :)